# \Wrapfigure problem

Tags: wrapfigure, textwidth

When I am using the command \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}, the column to the right appears white and all paragraphs aligned to left except the width of this figure. How to solve this issue?

the code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}

\centering

\includegraphics[width= 5 cm, height = 9 cm]{content/template/Actin filament structure.png}

\caption{\textbf{The structure of an actin filament}.}

\label{fig:actin filament structure}

\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example of code showing the issue.

Comment: Based on the 9cm height, it probably doesn't fit the space.  Try using {R} instead of {r}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes wrapfigure makes a bad estimate of the image's height. Here, getting a way to large estimate. While I was not able to reproduce it with the fragment you have shown (what is the rest of your document?), I know how to hotfix it: besides `\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}` you can do

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[17]{r}{0.3\textwidth}
```

This sets the wrapfigure to a height of 17 lines in the text. Tweak the number till everything fits right.

Does that solve you problem?

Comment: Yes, Alright, a lot of thanks!!!